# Creating a splash page in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, splash-screen

I want to create a splash page for the app I'm creating using HTML5.
The **splash page** should be displayed while the **main page** is being loaded (but the display should be at least 2 seconds even if the main page was already loaded). Say my main page is called `main.html` and the splash page is called `index.html`

I'm new to JavaScript, so I would really appreciate code example in addition to any explanations.

Thank you!

Comment: Load the splash popup, and after two seconds start checking if the main page is loaded. As soon it is, close the splash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#splash').ready() 
            {
                $('#main').load('file.html');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#main').ready(function() {
                        $('#splash').remove();
                        window.location.href = "file.html";
                    });
                }, 2000);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="splash" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; z-index: 10;">
            <!--Put splash here-->
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <!-- keep empty -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Not really tested, might contain bugs...
Uses jQuery

Comment: Thank you, debugging your code helped me improve my java script skills and I also got what I needed!  :-)

Comment: He wrote *java script*